I want to filter the salary data according to the radio button text
In the code I want filter the data of salary Array  when i clicked on the radio button. The render data should be filtered accordingly to the text on the radio button. The check box Array filtering is working fine after applying the same concept the radio type is not working.
code is:
import {Component} from 'react'
    import Cookies from '[Jobby App](https://i.sstatic.net/ZLavA3Qm.png)js-cookie'
    import {FcSearch} from 'react-icons/fc'
    import {IoMdStar} from 'react-icons/io'
    import {BsFillBagFill} from 'react-icons/bs'
    import {ImLocation2} from 'react-icons/im'
- import './index.css'

const employmentTypesList = [
  {
    label: 'Full Time',
    employmentTypeId: 'FULLTIME',
  },
  {
    label: 'Part Time',
    employmentTypeId: 'PARTTIME',
  },
  {
    label: 'Freelance',
    employmentTypeId: 'FREELANCE',
  },
  {
    label: 'Internship',
    employmentTypeId: 'INTERNSHIP',
  },
]

const salaryRangesList = [
  {
    salaryRangeId: '1000000',
    label: '10 LPA and above',
  },
  {
    salaryRangeId: '2000000',
    label: '20 LPA and above',
  },
  {
    salaryRangeId: '3000000',
    label: '30 LPA and above',
  },
  {
    salaryRangeId: '4000000',
    label: '40 LPA and above',
  },
]

class JobsRoute extends Component {
  state = {
    profileList: [],
    jobsList: [],`your text`
    searchInput: '',
    EmployList: [],
    SalaryList: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderProfile()
    this.renderJobsApi()
  }

  searchBox = event => {
    this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value})
  }

  renderProfile = async () => {
    const url = 'https://apis.ccbp.in/profile'
    const jwtToken = Cookies.get('jwt_token')

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
      },
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, options)
    if (response.ok === true) {
      const data = await response.json()
      const updatedData = {
        name: data.profile_details.name,
        profileImageUrl: data.profile_details.profile_image_url,
        shortBio: data.profile_details.short_bio,
      }

      this.setState({profileList: updatedData})
    }
  }

  renderProfileList = () => {
    const {profileList} = this.state
    const {name, profileImageUrl, shortBio} = profileList

    return (
      <div className="profile-container">
        <div className="profile">
          <img src={profileImageUrl} alt="profileImage" />
          <h1 style={{color: 'blue+  '}}>{name}</h1>
          <p style={{color: 'black'}}>{shortBio}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderJobsApi = async () => {
    const {EmployList, SalaryList, searchInput} = this.state
    const JobsUrl = `https://apis.ccbp.in/jobs?employment_type=${EmployList}&package_per_annum=${SalaryList}&search=${searchInput}`
    const jwtJobsToken = Cookies.get('jwt_token')

    const JobOptions = {
      method: 'GET',

      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtJobsToken} `,
      },
    }
    const response = await fetch(JobsUrl, JobOptions)
    if (response.ok === true) {
      const jobData = await response.json()
      const updatedJobsData = jobData.jobs.map(jobItem => ({
        companyLogoUrl: jobItem.company_logo_url,
        employmentType: jobItem.employment_type,
        id: jobItem.id,
        jobDescription: jobItem.job_description,
        location: jobItem.location,
        packagePerAnnum: jobItem.package_per_annum,
        rating: jobItem.rating,
        title: jobItem.title,
      }))

      this.setState({jobsList: updatedJobsData})
    }
  }

  EmployLists = event => {
    const {EmployList} = this.state
    const CheckboxNotInLists = EmployList.filter(
      each => each === event.target.id,
    )
    if (CheckboxNotInLists.length === 0) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          EmployList: [...prevState.EmployList, event.target.id],
        }),
        this.renderJobsApi,
      )
    } else {
      const filterData = EmployList.filter(each => each !== event.target.id)
      this.setState(
        {
          EmployList: filterData,
        },
        this.renderJobsApi,
      )
    }
  }

  SalaryLists = event => {
    const {SalaryList} = this.state
    const salaryRangeId = event.target.id
    const isChecked = event.target.checked

    if (isChecked) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        SalaryList: [...prevState.SalaryList, salaryRangeId],
      }))
    } else {
      const filteredList = SalaryList.filter(id => id !== salaryRangeId)
      this.setState({
        SalaryList: filteredList,
      })
    }
  }

  buttonSearch = () => {
    this.renderJobsApi()
  }

  searchInputDown = event => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.renderJobsApi()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {jobsList, searchInput} = this.state
    return (
      <div className="job-container">
        <div className="profile-container">
          <div style={{marginLeft: '38px'}}>{this.renderProfileList()}</div>
          <hr style={{marginTop: '25px', marginLeft: '38px'}} />
          <p style={{color: 'white', marginTop: '10px', marginLeft: '38px'}}>
            Type of Employment
          </p>
          <ul className="unordered">
            {employmentTypesList.map(each => (
              <li key={each.employmentTypeId} className="listed">
                <input
                  onChange={this.EmployLists}
                  value={each.label}
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="checkbox"
                  id={each.employmentTypeId}
                />
                <label className="label-name" htmlFor={each.employmentTypeId}>
                  {each.label}
                </label>{' '}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <hr style={{marginTop: '25px', marginLeft: '38px'}} />
          <p style={{color: 'white', marginTop: '10px', marginLeft: '38px'}}>
            Salary Range
          </p>
          <ul className="unordered">
            {salaryRangesList.map(each => (
              <li key={each.salaryRangeId} className="listed">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value={each.label}
                  onChange={this.SalaryLists}
                  id={each.salaryRangeId}
                />
                <label className="label-name" htmlFor={each.salaryRangeId}>
                  {each.label}
                </label>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="search-container">
          <div className="search-box">
            <input
              type="search"
              className="search-bar"
              placeholder="Search"
              value={searchInput}
              onChange={this.searchBox}
              onKeyDown={this.searchInputDown}
            />
            <button
              className="search"
              onClick={this.buttonSearch}
              type="button"
              data-testid="searchButton"
              aria-label="Search"
            >
              <FcSearch className="search-icon" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul>
            {jobsList.map(jobItem => (
              <li value={this.SalaryList} className="list-jobdetails">
                <div className="container">
                  <img
                    src={jobItem.companyLogoUrl}
                    alt="job details company logo"
                    className="job-image"
                  />
                  <div className="title-rating">
                    <h1>{jobItem.title}</h1>
                    <div className="star-rating">
                      <IoMdStar className="star" />
                      <p>{jobItem.rating}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="location-employment">
                  <div className="loc-emp">
                    <ImLocation2 />
                    <p style={{marginLeft: '8px'}}>{jobItem.location}</p>

                    <BsFillBagFill style={{marginLeft: '13px'}} />
                    <p style={{marginLeft: '8px'}}>{jobItem.employmentType}</p>
                  </div>
                  <p>{jobItem.packagePerAnnum}</p>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <h2 style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>Description</h2>
                <p style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>{jobItem.jobDescription}</p>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default JobsRoute

salary details should be
filtered after clicking the radio button (salary Range)

I think I have a little adjustment that you could try:


// Update the state to hold a single selected salary range ID
state = {
  // Other state properties...
  selectedSalaryRangeId: '', // Add this one here
}

// Modify the SalaryLists function
SalaryLists = event => {
  const { selectedSalaryRangeId } = this.state;
  const salaryRangeId = event.target.id;
  const isChecked = event.target.checked;

  // So when a radio button is checked, update the state with the selected salary range ID
  if (isChecked) {
    this.setState({ selectedSalaryRangeId: salaryRangeId });
  } else {
    // If the radio button is unchecked simply clear the selectedSalaryRangeId
    this.setState({ selectedSalaryRangeId: '' });
  }
}

// You can then update the renderJobsApi function to use the selectedSalaryRangeId for filtering
renderJobsApi = async () => {
  const { selectedSalaryRangeId, searchInput } = this.state;
  const JobsUrl = `https://apis.ccbp.in/jobs?employment_type=${EmployList}&package_per_annum=${selectedSalaryRangeId}&search=${searchInput}`;
  // Rest of the function remains the same...
}




I very much appreciate your efforts Lanre. But actually the adjustment we did is not showing expected output. Let me confirm is this code is in correct format .


            {salaryRangesList.map(each => (
              


                  {each.label}
                
